# Debugging with laravel Fluent Query Builder

Tags: debugging, laravel, fluent, laravel-3

Im building a project in laravel 3 and wondering how you can debug Fluent Query Builder ie. get the error message or the produced SQL in order to see what im doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you enable the profiler in Laravel 3 it will show you the executed queries once the page has loaded. You can enable it by setting the `profiler` option to `true` in `application/config/application.php`

Comment: Thanks :D Thats quite handy :D